Purpose of generateStaticParams in next js, and is it worth it?
I've been reading the next.js docs, and there are two things that puzzle me about the generateStaticParams.
#1: 1st thing that puzzles me is the paragraph at https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#generating-static-params .

The primary benefit of the generateStaticParams function is its smart retrieval of data. If content is fetched within the generateStaticParams function using a fetch request, the requests are automatically memoized. This means a fetch request with the same arguments across multiple generateStaticParams, Layouts, and Pages will only be made once, which decreases build times.

So the primary benefit is that generateStaticParams helps other occurences of generateStaticParams, making them faster? That makes me think that it's a no brainer NOT to use generateStaticParams at all, which nullifies the build time impact completely.

#2 I understand that it also generates the route before a request has been made as well. But that's what makes me wonder.. I'll try explaining with an example:
Case 1: For our blog posts, we don't use SSG (generateStaticParams):
As far as I know, once a dynamic route like /blog/posts/[slug] is hit, the content is generated at request time, stored in the "Full Route Cache" which is persistent, and then sent to the visitor's browser. Any visits from now on, whether it be 5 mins later or a month, will be sent from this cache. Negating the need for a re-render on server.
Case 2: We do use SSG (generateStaticParams):
All the possible routes are generated at build time and stored at the "Full Route Cache", and any requests to them will be delivered from that cache, negating the need for a re-render on server.
Now let's say in Case 1, we had all of our blog posts visited by previous visitors. And that will cause every rendered blogpost page to be stored in the "Full Route Cache", which effectively brings it to the same state with Case 2.
So in the end, all generateStaticParams can do for us is just making the first ever request a little bit faster. But in return, we lost the ability to run revalidation on those routes. <-- I'm not sure about that one

the TLDR version of my questions are:

The primary benefit to generateStaticParams is said to be faster generation times. The alternative is not generating these pages AT ALL, which definitely results in faster build time. Am I missing a point?
Disregarding the FIRST EVER visit to a route, Is there any runtime performance difference between if we use generateStaticParams or not ?


I might have some errors in my understanding of the concepts. If so, I apologize and would appreciate some enlightenment!

I am no expert at all, also struggling with this. But I understand it like this. There's a difference in FullRouteCache and static html file (which generateStaticParams should make). With FullRouteCache I can still imagine more cpu/code being processed to decide where it is. With static html, it should be very fast, no hard logic.

@FrantišekHeča That's what i'm not sure about. I don't see any static htmls generated with generateStaticParams. It looks as if it's doing the exact same thing.
